# Icons not displaying in Lambda app with API Gateway using Golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a web application using AWS Lambda and API Gateway with Golang. My application serves some static files including icons, but I am facing an issue where the icons are not being displayed.

I have set up my routes in API Gateway as follows:

```
/ GET
/data GET
/{clientID} GET
/detail GET
/icons GET
/login POST
/reports GET
```

In my Go application, I have set up a static file server for the icons directory:

```
r := gin.Default()
r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
r.Static("/icons", "./icons")
```

In my HTML files, I am referencing the icons like so:

```
<img src="/icons/icon.png" alt="Icon">
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on what might be going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!